# React fetch data every 500 ms or less

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I'm trying to check my data every time they update by seeing other forums try to use:

```
  async function fetchData() {
    try {
      const url = `${baseUrl}/api/turn`;
      const res = await axios.get(url);
      setTurns(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
      const timer = setInterval(() => {
        fetchData();
      }, 500);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(timer);
      };
  }, []);
```

It works but it throws me this error

[image]

And it makes sense ... but I tried to find more information to solve it but I couldn't solve it.

I need some help with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case of class component, you can call the function in componentDidMount(), which will ensure that component has already been mounted.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because you're trying to setState after component is unmounted.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
      let isMounted = true;
      const timer = setInterval(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
         try {
          const url = `${baseUrl}/api/turn`;
          const res = await axios.get(url);
          if (isMounted) {
          setTurns(res.data);}
         } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
         }
        }
        fetchData();
      }, 500);
      return () => {
        isMounted = false
        clearInterval(timer);
      };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

I take it this error is probably sporadic?  I also assume `setTurns` is a `useState` setter.

I think what could happen is that when the component is unmounted, you correctly cancel any pending timer, but you're not actually cancelling any async request.  I'd suggest restructuring so that a new request is only emitted 500ms after the old one completes, because right now you could issue multiple requests if the network is slow.